# MongoDB user roles

Tags: mongodb, mlab, mongodb-roles

I am trying to grant my users of my app a role that will allow them to do anything they want in a particular database.

Also, I assume for my simple application, when the user *first* registers with the application, I then, and only then, grant them that role?

What is shorthand in JavaScript to grant a user a "do anything" role for a particular database?

```
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser(
  "myUsersName",
  [
    {
      role: "doAnythingAndEverything", db: "userDBName"
    },
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The role combining every privileges (readWrite, dbAdmin and userAdmin) for a specific database is "dbOwner". As far as I know, there is no shorthand to grant a role other than `db.grantRolesToUser`

```
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser(
  "myUsersName",
  [
    {
      role: "dbOwner", db: "userDBName"
    },
  ]
);
```

Comment: thanks, any idea how to do this programmatically with Node.js instead of at the command line?

Comment: In node.js:
var adminDb = db.admin();
adminDb.grantRolesToUser(...)